# Function to subset dataframe using pattern list argument

Tags: regex, r, function, dataframe

I have a pattern list

```
patternlist <- list('one' = paste(c('a','b','c'),collapse="|"), 'two' = paste(1:5,collapse="|"), 'three' = paste(c('k','l','m'),collapse="|"))
```

that I want to select from to extract rows from a data frame

```
dataframez <- data.frame('letters' = c('a','b','c'), 'numbers' = 1:3, 'otherletters' = c('k','l','m'))
```

with this function

```
pattern.record <- function(x, column="letters", value="one")
{
  if (column %in% names(x))
  {
   result <- x[grep(patternlist$value, x$column, ignore.case=T),]
  }
  else
  {
    result <- NA
  }
  return(result)
}
```

oddly enough, I get an error when I run it:

```
> pattern.record(dataframez)
 Error in grep(patternlist$value, x$column, ignore.case = T) : 
  invalid 'pattern' argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your use of the `` `$` `` operator.

In your function, it is looking a column \ named element called `column`

It is far simpler here to use `` `[[` ``

Then `x[[column]]` uses what `column` is defined as, not `column` as a name.

The relevant lines in `` ?`$` `` are

> Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list. The main difference is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does. x$name is equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]. Also, the partial matching behavior of [[ can be controlled using the exact argument.

You are trying to use `value` and `column` as *computed indices* (i.e. *computing* what `value` and `column` are defined as), thus you need `` `[[` ``.

The function becomes

```
pattern.record <- function(x, column="letters", value="one", pattern_list)
{
  if (column %in% names(x))
  {
    result <- x[grep(pattern_list[[value]], x[[column]], ignore.case=T),]
  }
  else
  {
    result <- NA
  }
  return(result)
}

pattern.record(dataframez, patternlist = pattern_list)

##   letters numbers otherletters
## 1       a       1            k
## 2       b       2            l
## 3       c       3            m
```

note that I've also added an argument`pattern_list` so it does not depend on an object named `patternlist` existing somewhere in the parent environments (in your case the global environment.

Comment: Actually R _is_ parsing `column` ... it's just not evaluating `column`. Otherwise I agree completely.